# How can I create a window program using Lua in Visual Studio Code

Tags: lua, window, game-development

I would like to know what functions/parameters I would need to create a program that would open a window using the Lua language in Visual Studio, for things such as making games. Most of the functions I've used, like ui.Window() or add_window have not worked for me, coming from other Lua tutorials on YouTube and such.

Answer (score 0):

Lua itself doesn't come with a way to create a GUI. If you want to do that, you need to set up a library that does it, e.g., [IUP](https://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/). See http://lua-users.org/wiki/GraphicalUserInterfaceToolkits for some more choices.